# Can't use socat to process HTTP request via serial port

Tags: http, sockets, go, socat

I'm trying to use socat in order to process incoming HTTP requests and send them via serial port to a board which will process it and send the response back. The problem is that concurrent requests will be discarded, and it will process only the first one. I tried running `socat -d -d -d -d TCP-LISTEN:8081,fork,tcp-defer-accept=1 FILE:/dev/ttyACM0,b115200,raw,lock` in order to achieve that, but only processes the first request. I implemented a bridge in go which does what I described, but the ideal approach would be using socat. Currently the handler of the socket, which aslo parses the request looks like this:

```
var mutex sync.Mutex
func Handler(conn net.Conn, s *serial.Port) {
mutex.Lock()
defer mutex.Unlock()
defer conn.Close()

buf := make([]byte, 65535)

l := 0
cl := 0
readingBody := false
var index int
var index2 int
for {
    n, err := conn.Read(buf[l:])
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    l += n
    if !readingBody {
        if strings.Contains(string(buf), "\r\n\r\n") {
            if !strings.Contains(string(buf), "Content-Length:") {
                break
            } else {
                index = strings.Index(string(buf), "Content-Length:")
                index2 = strings.Index(string(buf), "\r\n\r\n")
                indexcl := strings.Index(string(buf[index:]), "\r\n")
                cl, err = strconv.Atoi(string(buf[index+16 : index+indexcl]))
                if cl == 0 {
                    break
                }
                readingBody = true
                if l-cl == index2+4 {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if l-cl == index2+4 {
            break
        }
    }
}
fmt.Println("REQUEST")
if v {
    fmt.Println(string(buf) + "\r\n")
}

n, err := s.Write(buf[:l])
if err != nil {
    s.Close()
    log.Fatal(err)
}
_ = n

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(s)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
var b bytes.Buffer

l = 0
cl = 0
readingBody = false

for scanner.Scan() {
    b.Write([]byte(scanner.Text()))
    l++
    if !readingBody {
        if strings.Contains(b.String(), "\r\n\r\n") {
            if !strings.Contains(b.String(), "Content-Length:") {
                break
            } else {
                index = strings.Index(b.String(), "Content-Length:")
                index2 = strings.Index(b.String(), "\r\n\r\n")
                cl, err = strconv.Atoi(string(b.Bytes()[index+16 : index2]))
                if cl == 0 {
                    break
                }
                readingBody = true
                if l-cl == index2+4 {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if l-cl == index2+4 {
            break
        }
    }
}

fmt.Println("RESPONSE")
if v {
    fmt.Println(string(b.Bytes()) + "\r\n")
}

n, err = conn.Write(b.Bytes())
}
```

Is there any way to use socat so that the processing is made in a similar way queueing requests until response for the previous are given?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `defer-accept` TCP-mode option of `socat`? It looks like tailored for your case.

Comment: Another question: can you use `netcat` (`nc`) instead of `socat`? It does not accept multiple connections at the same time, and by default even exits after serving the first connection unless a special command-line option is suppled which makes it work in a loop.

Comment: Well, no, `netcat` cannot do serial. But you could try to chain `socat` in TCP listening mode with `nc` which would accept incoming requests and send them to `socat`. This would look weird, but if you insist on not writing any custom code, that could possibly do the trick.

Comment: Did you try the max-children=1 option?

Comment: I tried using the max-children option, but I have seen that requests that are being processed get discarded to process new ones. As for the socat use with nc, how would the command be? The expected behaviour is to queue requests and process them one by one.